# Finding and counting text in a text field with PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a postgres db, I need to find, extract and count URLs embedded in a text column. (Pseudocode)

```
SELECT id, 
  body, 
  xxx? AS the_url,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(the_url)) as count
FROM messages 
    WHERE body LIKE '%://%' 
GROUP BY the_url;
```

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `FILTER` combined with `count(*)` to count how many records in your table contain a certain pattern, e.g.

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE body LIKE '%://%') 
FROM messages;
```

If you want to count the occurrences of a certain text inside a column you might wanna try this:

```
SELECT id,body,
  array_length(string_to_array(body,'%://%'),1)-1 
FROM messages;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=bf0f3666586f4e6acac055a1a8306c7f)

Comment: Almost there! The first one is good.
For the second one, I'd need an output like that:
URL | number_of_occurances. Where occurrences is across the column, not in the individual row.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jan you mean this? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=974380441ef2211453f6a1bc1609abd4

Comment: this should search for a certain number of occurrences of a give text in the column `body`

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id,body,
    array_length(string_to_array(body,'foo'),1)-1 AS qt
  FROM messages) j
WHERE qt > 0 

does it! You are great, thanks a lot!